# How to interpret 'electron energy above fermi level (eV)'?

Tags: electrons, scattering-cross-section, mean-free-path

In some mean free path graphs, I see 'electron energy above Fermi level (eV)' on the x-axis See figure:[image] What does it mean? Is it electrons kinetic energy in the material?

What happens if the graph states only 'Energy (eV)'?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the kinetic energy inside the material. The difference with the energy outside the material is small: it is just the work function, a few eV. This does not matter in the second figure, where data start at 100 eV.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The second figure was just an illustration. In some studies data goes to almost ~ 10 eV. In addition, the saddle point of the curve is also on focus. So, I don't want to make a systematic error.